# ggplot scale_fill_stepsn and equally spaced legend color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a map that uses the ggplot scale_fill_stepn function to color a US counties map with unequal breaks.   The resulting legend spaces the color scale according to the relative distance between the breaks.   How do I make the blocks of color in the legend equally spaced?

```
library(urbnmapr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Obtain county polygon data
states_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "states", sf = TRUE)
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE)

# Assign random values of data to each count  
counties_sf$value = runif(length(counties_sf$county_fips), min=-3.0, max=3.0)

# Remove AK and HI - lower 48 only 
states_sf <- states_sf[!(states_sf$state_abbv %in% c("HI","AK")),]
counties_sf <- counties_sf[!(counties_sf$state_abbv %in% c("HI","AK")),]

# Plot county level data with a discrete legend 

data_levels <- c(-3,-1.5, -0.8, -0.5, -0.25,-0.1,0.1,0.25,0.5,.8,1.5,3)
level_colors <- c('#aa411c','#bf662e','#d59042','#ecb554','#fddc67','#FFFF73','#cbff66','#87f345','#00e601','#00b300','#009a00','#007b00')

length(data_levels)
length(level_colors)

counties_sf %>%
  ggplot() +
  # Overlay State Outlines
  # Plot county data and fill with value
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = value), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  # Remove grid lines from plot
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks=data_levels, colors=level_colors, limits=c(-3,3)) + 
  labs(title='This Data is Completely Random', 
       fill='Deviation from Trend') + 
  theme_map() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width=unit(1.5,"cm"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color="black", size=2),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.spacing = unit(1,"cm"),
        legend.justification = "center",
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))  +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: One option would be to use `guide_bins` instead of `guide_colourbar`.

Comment: That does the trick.  Thanks! It creates other visualization items to be corrected.  For example, this particular guide places an "axis" (according to the docs) that when axis=FALSE leaves a white space between the legend boxes.    I'd like to eliminate that and have them next to each other w/o white space.